# How to embed an MP4 inside a PDF?

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, adobe, mp4

I am a happy user of [img2pdf](https://superuser.com/q/687849/106444). This tool does the minimal amount of work to put a series of JPEG 2000/JPEG/PNG images into a PDF "enveloppe". However I am now faced with a new challenge: embed a MP4 file into a PDF "enveloppe".

I see that commercial tool can do it, as seen at:

- [Add audio, video, and interactive objects to PDFs](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html)

Here is one such sample PDF file (no Flash required on windows in this sample):

- https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9/-/issues/9#note_345903962

  - https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9/uploads/90fddd777e0ec514c39c924cd8d3b688/video_test.pdf

It seems to have been introduced in ISO 32000-1 ([PDF 1.7 Extension Level 5](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000_1.pdf))

I am looking for a solution which will use the *Rich Media annotation* inside the PDF stream.

There are dozen of duplicated questions on superuser/stackoverflow, which all pretty much refer to imagemagick/convert command line tool. But in my case, `convert` expand the images into a multi-page PDF (which is not my desired behavior):

```
$ convert input.mp4 output.pdf
$ pdfinfo output.pdf 
Title:          out
Producer:       https://imagemagick.org
CreationDate:   Wed Aug 19 15:38:01 2020 CEST
ModDate:        Wed Aug 19 15:38:01 2020 CEST
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1601
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      352 x 288 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      534407296 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

with:

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

and

```
$ file input.mp4 
input.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]
$ ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json  -show_streams input.mp4 | grep codec_long_name
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
```

How would you embed an MP4 inside a PDF now that Flash support is being removed from Acrobat (Dec 2020) ? The solution should be on the command line (linux based system).

Comment: Unfortunately looking into this I couldn't find an existing tool that would do it for you. PyMupdf is an easy to use library that you could use to embed the file in the pdf (which is required to get this to work.) but I think you'd have to write some code of  your own to get the media extensions to work.

Comment: There is no standard solution to embed MP4 directly into a PDF using command line tools. However, you could consider using a multimedia package like LaTeX to create a PDF with an embedded MP4 file. A package called media9 allows to embed audio and video files, including MP4, in a PDF document. To use it, you would need to have a working LaTeX environment.

Comment: https://softans.com/question/how-to-embed-an-mp4-inside-a-pdf/#comment-485

Answer (score 2):

It was common and still possible to use Rich Media Annotation to include 3D animations or Media files within a PDF. Generally you need top end editors such as Acrobat PRO but there are a few LaTeX editor modules that some times work, ***thus can be PDFLaTeX compiled from Linux command line.*** for outdated example app see http://www.acrotex.net/blog/?cat=22 for an overflow example see https://www.overleaf.com/project/5ff76fa5686edd3e034cfedb and for prior adobe reply (but did not work for a while) see

[> Embedded media, as well as referenced media outside a PDF file, may be played with a variety of player software. (In some situations, the player software may be the conforming reader itself.)](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/flash-player-still-required-for-pdf-documents/m-p/9628113#M86325)

[image]

***[Later comments]*** Adobe shot selves in foot with the poor closure of their buggy insecure SWFlash and only improved some rich media handling in more recent Windows Reader versions Acrobat DC - **21.001.20135 plus !** having turned their back on maintaining Portable Document Format Readers for Linux/Mac. What is needed is a push to use HTMLZ as ideal Rich Media Format but that would need Google Chrome to run with the bouton (pun).

Its NOT recommended except for 3D PDF as most methods require manual over-ridding security measures to STOP runtime applications within a PDF.

SWF/Flash is no longer acceptable for that reason. MicroSoft Edge (pre-chrome) made an attempt at imbedding pdf links to You Tube videos but AFAIK that was abandoned. Thus  RMA pdfs can not run in more common browsers they need specialist viewers and the best viewer for Linux is possibly Okular but I cannot run that file in my version.

When opening a 3D file you need to jump through multiple hoops to allow and for floating video it may not even run. your links lead to this media example which can run inline (seen above) or better pop out with system application controls.

[image]

However in some viewers it needs to be manually exported from the pdf archive as an attachment to be run in a system media player. and for browser presentations it can be a local hyperlink like this.

[image]

Using Okular on windows it does not ask prior to running content but that could be because it found no suitable player, however it allows me to link to a local file and run that in system viewer.

[image]

For everyday presentations its easier to include the media file in a zip with the pdf or PowerPoint presentation for running locally from the pdf.

### [Updated PoC for building using alternative raw mp4's]

It is possible to write a complex PDF in text on the console ([Here is a 203 line example in Windows CMD](https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/MAKE-PDF.cmd)), **[Typical output](https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/demo.pdf)** I would not normally suggest that as an answer to a highly complex structure such as Rich Media, but a simpler all platforms approach **is possible** with a small nip and tuck of header & trailer, plus variable mp4 body.

### Method

Store the text header as a pre-set template then append the mp4 without changes finally add the PDF trailer with modified values from file lengths. too long to describe its now 216 lines (with comments and notes) and working well for PDFs in xChange as a drag and drop any 1-9 MB.mp4 (need to up that math value to 1999 MB) or send file to or CLI command for single files, but the programming can be done simply as I did using CMD or OS script and the result generated in windows with roughly scripting around

`copy /b  head2.bin + pixels.mp4 + tail2.bin all2.pdf /b`

the secondary part is how to use text to overlay a cover image in as few lines as possible
[image]

So that is now scripted to add variable length of any video.mp4  so I simply run or drag and drop per consol and a dialog can show progress and show feedback and get inputs such as names or dimensions via **`mp4toPDF video.mp4 [output.pdf]`** so next step is user to add the caption (perhaps other scalars) as  variable argument(s).

[image]

The number of PDF viewers supporting Rich Media is dwindling, I can't use Acrobat nor Edge either, so it seems I need to use Tracker (below) which is much more versatile and has many other advantages, but is Windows only.

[image]

or Cross platform Foxit. However, on Windows Foxit is way inferior with no resize or search bar or other floating controls.

[image]

So currently I can add via script and run in either edit viewer a mp4 or wmv or other video under 2GB but the field (locked aspect in Foxit) has no cover (plain white) however if I move an image over the top it seems to block out action but under white its unseen so need to resolve that transparency issue, have settled on stamp bigger white area to keep the run button visible. but having some issues with auto stamping its affecting run button even when the two are not overlapping
[image]

Breaking news, OMG, no idea which way this will help any one, other than the "Revenue Men"

> Microsoft Edge’s new PDF viewer is powered by Adobe, and it won’t let you forget that. In an announcement on its website, Microsoft says it’s replacing Edge’s existing PDF viewer with one from Adobe Acrobat, which includes some “advanced” features that are available if you’re willing to pay for them.

Answer (score 0):

Video controls support are disabled in Adobe Acrobat, and is not supported by web browsers. Although you want ta add video with video controls, you can use Adobe Actrobat DC Pro, and you can automatize it using Action wizard.

Check this out https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html

Answer (score -2):

You can make a python script to embed your video.

Thanks to pyPdf2 api, you can use the addAttachment method to embed your video.

https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2