# How to edit and save to multiple pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, batch-processing, pdfbox, jspdf

Is there a way to fast do this or a tool ,command to achieve this .

Edit a number by increase and save to a new file.
My existing pdf (document.pdf) include number `1001` , i want to edit `1001` to many other number and save .

```
edit `1001` to `1002` and save as document2.pdf
edit `1001` to `1003` and save as document3.pdf
edit `1001` to `1004` and save as document4.pdf
edit `1001` to `1005` and save as document5.pdf
edit `1001` to `1006` and save as document6.pdf
edit `1001` to `1007` and save as document7.pdf
edit `1001` to `1008` and save as document8.pdf
...
edit `1001` to `1300` and save as document300.pdf
```

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you want to modify an existing PDF? Or create many PDFs that are slightly different?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i want to edit my existing PDF and save to many pdf

Comment: Is the existing number in a form field? If not, the easiest way would be to draw a white rectangle over the existing number and then the new number. However the old text would still be there, so it would make sense only for immediate printing and then throw the file away. Actually changing the PDF would be tricky and depend on the PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i see `http://www.a-pdf.com/text-replace/index.htm` can do my problem by replace ,do you have an alternative for `a-pdf text replace` ? . This can run by command line

Comment: This may or may not work, see here why: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed%3F

Comment: Pdfbox does not contain finished text replacement routines. You can create a text replacement tool for pdfs based on pdfbox but it's not a trivial task - you can find multiple q&a here on stackoverflow.com illustrating why it's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Without Code and simply a request here is one method.

Save a PDF head up to the point you want the number then inject the number then add the tail.

For example in Windows cmd shell `GenerateDocuments.cmd 5` would use

```
@echo off
If %1. LEQ 0 echo Usage: GenerateDocuments Number (as PDF where Number is 1 to 999)

Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&for /L %%B in (1,1,%1) do (
set "num=00%%B"
copy /b Head.tmp Document%%B.pdf>nul
echo.|set /p =!num:~-3!>>Document%%B.pdf
type Tail.tmp>>Document%%B.pdf 
)
exit /b
```

To generate 5 copies
[image]

Of course your head and tail need to be prebuilt with a gap where the number goes.

Same method can be used for a set of images or MP4 video as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71428472/10802527

Comment: what inside Head and tail ? ,this solution seem complicated

Comment: just need a free tool can replace text in pdf by command is ok , do you have it ?